# Can't make WebView2 work for Dotnet Framework Windows application

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to follow this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms

I have Microsoft Edge (Chromium) Canary channel and VS2019 installed.

So I...

- Create a C# Windows App
- I install the Microsoft.Web.WebView2 v0.9.579 *(it says to check "Include prerelease" when searching for Microsoft.Web.WebView2 on Nuget, but I don't see any prereleases)*
- I build the project as stated

But now I don't see a WebView2 control in the toolbox.

Do you guys get a WebView2 control in the toolbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problem according to the document, you could try to add Microsoft.Web.WebView2 pre-release version.

[image: here]

Comment: Yeah but the lastes version is 0.9.579 - no prereleases after that?

Comment: Click the small triangle, the drop-down list has a preview version

Comment: The latest version 0.9.579 has prereleases version. Before you search, you could click '✔' to include the prerelease version, like the first step in the picture.

Comment: I presume the v0.9.579 is a later (final) version than "v0.9.0579 Prerelease" ... so it is strange the WebView2 is only in the prerelease. But thanks .. I will try with the prerelease you showed me :)